# Minimum perimeter of an area

Tags: code-golf, math

Just a simple code golf function for fun, intentionally left open with few rules to see what creativity comes up.

**Input:** An integer representing the area of a rectangle.

**Output:** Two integers representing the side lengths of the rectangle that have the least perimeter for the area.  (In any order.)

**Test cases:**

```
25 => 5, 5
53 => 53, 1
4294967295 => 65537, 65535
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness here the corresponding OEIS numbers:  http://oeis.org/A033676 and  http://oeis.org/A033677

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### GolfScript (21 chars)

```
:^,{)^\%!},.,2/=)^1$/
```

This takes the input as a number on the stack and leaves the result as two numbers on the stack.

For fair comparison with Howard's solution, taking input on stdin and giving output on stdout separated by newline is **23 chars**:

```
~:^,{)^\%!},.,2/=)n^2$/
```

It works because this problem is trivial: it's just looking for the pair of factors closest to `sqrt(area)`.

[Online demo for a square](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzI1CjpeLHspXlwlIX0sLiwyLz0pXjEkLwpdcA%3D%3D); [online demo for a non-square](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzEwNQo6Xix7KV5cJSF9LC4sMi89KV4xJC8KXXA%3D).

Comment: I knew that my first try-and-post solution wouldn't last very long.

Comment: Runs out of memory on the last test case, otherwise seems to be working :)

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica <s>34</s> 26

Besides the explicit search there is a nice convergent series:

[image]

```
n = 27

{i=√n//.i_:>n/⌈n/⌊i⌋⌉,n/i}
```

> {3, 9}

Three previous approaches with 34 characters:

```
{#,n/#}&@FixedPoint[n/⌈n/⌊#⌋⌉&,√n]

For[i=√n,i>(i=n/⌈n/⌊i⌋⌉),];{i,n/i}

f@i_:=f[f@i=n/⌈n/⌊i⌋⌉]
{i=f@√n,n/i}

ClearAll[f]
```

Visualization:

```
p = FixedPointList[n/⌈n/⌊#⌋⌉ &, Sqrt[n]];

Plot[n/x, {x, 0, 11}, GridLines -> {Range@n, Range@n}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 10.2}, {0, 7.2}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.005], 
   Arrow[Transpose[{{n/p, ⌈p⌉}, {n/p, ⌊p⌋}, {⌈n/⌊p⌋⌉, ⌊p⌋}}, {2, 3, 1}]], 
  PointSize[0.02], Black, Point[{n/p[[-1]], p[[-1]]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: (this is not a function, but a snippet evaluating to the answer. Invalid according to [newer consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet), can somebody fix it? ...)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 (<s>63</s> 62)

```
n=input()
print[(i,n/i)for i in range(1,n)if i*i>=n/i*i==n][0]
```

This produces all pairs of integers (i, n/i) that could be the sides of the rectangle, starting from the first one greater or equal to the square root of n. It prints the first one.

Comment: You may save a single char if you take the reverse list, i.e. `i*i>=n` and then the first element `[0]`.

Comment: Is it just me or does it blow up on the last test case? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, because it goes through all the numbers from 1 to n, it scales very poorly. I actually had a much more elegant solution first that used a generator instead of a list comprehension, so it didn't generate unused elements, but it needed a few extra characters...

Comment: Follow-up on Levin's answer.
It fails on areas that are prime.
I.e. > python peri.py
401
Traceback (most recent call last): File "peri.py", line 2, in ? print[(i,n/i)for i in range(1,n)if i*i>=n/i*i==n][0]
IndexError: list index out of range Fix it by using n+1 inside the range. n=input()
print[(i,n/i)for i in range(1,n+1)if i*i>=n/i*i==n][0] > python peri.py
401
(401, 1) Cheers,
Gert

Answer (score 2):

**Golfscript (<s>46</s> <s>43</s> 40)**

```
~1{..*2$>!}{1$1$%!{.@@}*)}while;1$/p p];
```

No way to beat the math oriented languages at this challenge I suspect :)

Somewhat "long winded", it would be shorter to work with arrays, sadly they get a bit large with the last test case.

Basically what it does is similar to the Python solution, it loops from 1..sqrt(n), testing for an even multiplier, then just displaying the last value found.

Comment: You may replace `{X}{}if` with `{X}*` in this case.

Comment: @Howard Thanks, updated, although I see you soundly beat me with your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript, 30 characters

```
~:t,{[.t\/].~*t=1$~>!&\@if}*n*
```

Does a test on all numbers as many other solutions.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson For me it works fine, have a look [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjI1IgoKfjp0LHtbLnRcL10ufip0PTEkfj4hJlxAaWZ9Km4qCg%3D%3D&run=true).

Comment: Hm, I think my ruby install was severely broken, 32 bit ruby gets it right (but fails with out of memory on the last test case)

Answer (score 1):

**C# (178)**

```
int[] R(int n){var a=Enumerable.Range(1,n);var b=a.SelectMany(x=>a.SelectMany(y=>a.Select(_=>new{x,y}))).Where(f=>f.x*f.y== n).OrderBy(f=>f.x+f.y).First();return new[]{b.x,b.y};}
```

Pretty

```
int[] R(int n)
{
    var a = Enumerable.Range(1, n);
    var b = a.SelectMany(x => a.SelectMany(y => a.Select(_ => new { x, y }))).Where(f => f.x * f.y == n).OrderBy(f => f.x + f.y).First();
    return new[] { b.x, b.y };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, <s>73</s> 72 bytes

Saved one byte due to @ThomasKwa!

```
n->{for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);;i--)if(n%i<1)return new int[]{n/i,i};};
```

Lambda function, test with:

```
public class Rectangle {
    interface Test {
        int[] run(int v);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Test test = n->{for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);;i--)if(n%i<1)return new int[]{n/i,i};};

        int[] testCases = {1, 4, 8, 15, 47, 5040, 40320, 25, 53};
        for (int i : testCases) {
            int[] result = test.run(i);
            System.out.println(i + ": " + result[0] + ", " + result[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Finds the greatest divisor less than or equal to the square root of the area. Returns an `int[]`.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I knew there was a way to do it with `<` or `>`, I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## C, 54 bytes

```
f(x,y){for(y=sqrt(x);x%y;y--);printf("%d, %d",y,x/y);}
```

Just some general silliness.

Test if you like:

```
int main() {
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    f(a);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# 4.0: 79 characters

```
long[] P(long a){long r=0,s=0;while(++s<a/s)if(a%s==0)r=s;return new[]{r,a/r};}
```

If it weren't for the last test case, I could save 3 characters naming `long` to `int`.

In pretty format:

```
long[] Perimeter(long area)
{
    long result = 0;
    long side = 0;
    while (++side < area / side)
    {
        if (area % side == 0)
            result = side;
    }
    return new long[] { result, area / result };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, 71 bytes

Nothing fancy, find the pair of integers `(a, b)` closest to `sqrt(n)` such that `a*b==n`:

```
f;x;L(n,a,b)int*a,*b;{for(f=0,x=sqrt(n);x;--x)n%x||f++?:(*a=x,*b=n/x);}
```

If the function is allowed to work only on first invocation, then we can shrink it to 67 bytes:

```
f;x;L(n,a,b)int*a,*b;{for(x=sqrt(n);x;--x)n%x||f++?:(*a=x,*b=n/x);}
```

Test main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int testdata[] = {1, 4, 8, 15, 47, 5040, 40320};
  int x,y;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
     L(testdata[i], &x, &y);
     printf("%5d >  %dx%d\n", testdata[i], x, y);
  }
}
```

The code was originally written for [another golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66488), which is a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
÷Ɱ½ĖḞƑƇṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//w7fisa7CvcSW4biexpHGh@G5qv/Dh@KCrP//WzEwMDAsMjYsMjUsNDld)

Use a bunch of new quicks. (`ƇⱮƑ`)

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ọⱮ½TṪð,÷@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//4buN4rGuwr1U4bmqw7Asw7dA/8OH4oKs//9bMTAwMCwyNiwyNSw0OV0)

A port of my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167160/69850).