# Most logical rectangle formula from numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, geometry

#### Introduction

The task is simple. When given a number, output the most logical rectangle. To explain what a logical rectangle is, I provided some examples:

Input: `24`.

All possible rectangles have the form `A x B`, (`A` and `B` are both positive integers). So, all possible rectangles for `24` are:

- `1 x 24`
- `2 x 12`
- `4 x 6`

From this list, the most logical rectangle has the lowest `A + B`:

- `1 + 24 = 25`
- `2 + 12 = 14`
- `4 + 6 = 10`

You can see that `4 x 6` is the most logical rectangle, so we will output `4 x 6` (or `6 x 4`).

#### The rules

- Given an integer from `1` to `99999`, output the most logical rectangle.
- You may write a function or a program.
- The spaces in the output are not required.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

#### Test cases

```
Input >   Output

1     >   1 x 1
4     >   2 x 2
8     >   4 x 2 (or 2 x 4)
15    >   5 x 3 (or 3 x 5)
47    >   1 x 47 (or 47 x 1)
5040  >   72 x 70 (or 70 x 72)
40320 >   210 x 192 (or 192 x 210)
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 26 bytes

```
ri_mQ),W%{1$\%!}=:X/" x "X
```

or

```
ri_mQ{)1$\%!},W=):X/" x "X
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_mQ)%2CW%25%7B1%24%5C%25!%7D%3D%3AX%2F%22%20x%20%22X&input=24)

Finds the largest divisor less than or equal to the square root of the input as one of the two side lengths.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
jd[Kf!%QTs@Q2\x/QK
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=24&code=jd%5BKf%21%25QTs%40Q2%5Cx/QK&test_suite_input=1%0A4%0A8%0A15%0A47%0A5040%0A40320&test_suite=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=24&code=jd%5BKf%21%25QTs%40Q2%5Cx/QK&test_suite_input=1%0A4%0A8%0A15%0A47%0A5040%0A40320&test_suite=1)

Same idea as Martin's. Finds the first number >= floor(sqrt(n)), that divides n.

#### Explanation:

```
jd[Kf!%QTs@Q2\x/QK   implicit: Q = input number
          @Q2        sqrt(Q)
         s           floor, converts ^ to an integer
    f                find the first number T >= floor(sqrt(Q)), that satisfies:
     !%QT               Q mod T == 0
   K                 store this number in K
  [K         \x/QK   create the list [K, "x", Q/K]
jd                   join by spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8, 86 bytes

```
n->{for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);;i--)if(n%i==0){System.out.print(i+"x"+n/i);return;}};
```

Lambda function, test with:

```
public class Rectangle {
    interface Test {
        void run(int v);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Test test = n->{for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n);;i--)if(n%i==0){System.out.print(i+"x"+n/i);return;}};

        int[] testCases = {1, 4, 8, 15, 47, 5040, 40320};
        for (int i : testCases) {
            test.run(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Finds the largest divisor less than or equal to the square root of the input. Same concept as the CJam and Pyth answers.