# Differences of MaxMin Divisor Pairs (DMDP)

Tags: code-golf, division

## Let's talk about divisors...

Leaving out perfect squares (for a moment), all positive integers can be expressed as the **product** of 2 of their divisors. Quick example for `126`: Here are all the divisors of `126`
[image]

As you can see all the divisors can be paired. Here are what we will call the **Divisor Pairs**:
`[1, 126], [2, 63], [3, 42], [6, 21], [7, 18], [9, 14]`

For this challenge we will need only the **last pair of this list** (which is the **center pair** of the picture):
`[9,14]`.We will call this pair the **MaxMin Divisor Pair**.
The **Difference of MaxMin Divisor Pair** **(DMDP)** is the difference of the two elements of the pair which is `[9,14]=5`
One more example for `544`. The divisors are:

> [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, **17, 32**, 34, 68, 136, 272, 544]

and **DMDP(544)=15**  because `32-17=15`

What about the **perfect squares**? All perfect squares have **DMDP=0**
Let's take for example `64` with divisors

> {1, 2, 4, **8**, 16, 32, 64}

As you can see in this case the **MaxMin Divisor Pair** is `[8,8]` which has `DMDP=0`
we are almost done..

## The Challenge

Given an integer `n>0`, output **how many integers less than or equal to** `10000`, **have DMDP less than** `n`

## Test Cases

***input -> output***

```
1->100 (those are all the perfect squares)
5->492  
13->1201
369->6175  
777->7264  
2000->8478  
5000->9440  
9000->9888  
10000->10000   
20000->10000
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).Shortest answer in bytes **wins**.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have the `10000` as a second, variable, input?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but it would not add anything to the challenge. In this way I think it is easier for everybody to understand the challenge.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18349/194)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES7), 60 bytes

```
f=(n,i=1e4,j=i**.5|0)=>i?i%j?f(n,i,j-1):(i/j-j<n)+f(n,i-1):0
```

Probably exceeds your recursion limit, so you might prefer the iterative version for 70 bytes:

```
n=>[...Array(1e4)].map(g=(j=++i**.5|0)=>i%j?g(j-1):k+=i/j-j<n,i=k=0)|k
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>151</s> <s>111</s> <s>110</s> <s>101</s> 98 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0,x=10000,i;for(;x-->0;r-=i-n>>-1)for(i=x;i-->1&&(x<i*i|x%i>0||(i=x/i-i)>i););return r;}
```

-10 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-3 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jZFRT8MgFIXf@yvuiwuYUYuLNguWf@Be9mh8QNaZO7vbhtKlZu1vr7Tu1SABEs75knOAk7kYUTclnQ5fk61M28KrQbomAEi@dEdjS9jNx0UAy@aduArKGFaYrTceLeyAoICJhL7OiCuydV/ILIw1qmPtmOqF0JlyokBBWgvJZxWLXmEw5GrF@he8x6G/Q50Nw@w8oECukSuuXOk7R@DUOKkkpDbdRxVSb@GXGg9wDsXZ3jukz7d3MPy39f679eU5rTufNsHyFTFKLZN8ucOf/lPEl5sIsHneRog8zyPEY3i9WM84so0jyz/9o8yNGZNx@gE)

```java
n->{                  // Method with integer as parameter and return-type
  int r=0,            //  Result-integer, starting at 0
      x=10000,        //  Index-integer `x` for the outer loop, starting at 10,000
      i;              //  Index-integer `i` for the inner loop, uninitialized
  for(;x-->0;         //  Loop `x` in the range (10000, 0]:
      r-=i-n>>-1)     //   If the MaxMin-Divisor Pair's difference is lower than the input,
                      //    add 1 to the result (after every iteration)
    for(i=x;i-->1     //   Inner loop `i` in the range (`x`, 1]:
        &&(x<i*i      //    If the current square of `i` is smaller than or equals to `x`,
           |x%i>0     //    and the current `x` is divisible by `i`:
           ||(i=x/i-i)//     Calculate the MaxMin-Division difference
             >i););   //     And stop the inner loop
  return r;}          //  After the loops, return the result
```

Comment: You can use `for(i=1,i+=Math.sqrt(x);--i>0;)if(...` to save 1 byte.

Comment: Don't have time to try it myself, but would it be shorter to have the inner loop start from x and have an extra variable for the current minimum?

Comment: 101 bytes: `n->{int r=0,x=10000,i;for(;x-->0;r-=i-n>>-1)for(i=x;i-->1;)if(x>=i*i&x%i<1){i=x/i-i;break;}return r;}`

Comment: @Nevay Thanks again, really need to remember `x>=i*i` as alternative for using `Math.sqrt`, since this is the second time you've golfed that in my code.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.

```
ȷ4RÆDạU$Ṃ€<⁸S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//yLc0UsOGROG6oVUk4bmC4oKsPOKBuFP///8yMDAw)

Comment: `ÆDạ"Ṛ$Ṃ` saves you a byte over `ÆDạ:@¥⁸Ṃ` (I had `ạ"ṚṂ`...`ȷ4RÆDÇ€<⁸S` for 15 - too similar - EDIT: hmm or was it, no `:` involved... what do you think?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think you should post [this 13-byter](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//yLc0UsOGROG6oVUk4bmC4oKsPOKBuFP///8yMDAw)

Comment: Oh wow. nah you go for it, I saved you one byte that saves another 2!

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 73 <s>77</s> bytes

Thanks to @Guiseppe for the 4 bytes

```r
sum(sapply(1:1e4,function(x)min(abs((w=which(x%%1:x<1))-rev(w))))<scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFRCoAgEAXA0whvoUChfsQOY2IopIlm2umtmTxGqQFFp3S@EFLYZTpqNLe/IjoFH6H3ArStOW8cOmNCdiWI5mwfNPqpYnQE0Vg55@MD)

Have lost the vectorize function to calculate the DMDP and is now using a sapply over the function.  The truthies for items which are less than the input are summed for the result.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the DMDP is the min diff of that factor list! Very nice. I think `sum(sapply(1:1e4,function(x)min(abs((w=which(x%%1:x<1))-rev(w))))<scan())` is a bit shorter

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
Count[Divisors~Array~1*^4,a_/;#+a[[i=⌈Tr[1^a]/2⌉]]>a[[-i]]]&
```

[Try it on Wolfram Sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com)

### Usage

```
f = Count[Divisors~Array~1*^4,a_/;#+a[[i=⌈Tr[1^a]/2⌉]]>a[[-i]]]&
```

```
f[1]
```

> ```
> 100
> ```

```
f /@ {1, 5, 13, 369, 777, 2000, 5000, 9000, 10000, 20000}
```

> ```
> {100, 492, 1201, 6175, 7264, 8478, 9440, 9888, 10000, 10000}
> ```

### Explanation

```
Divisors~Array~1*^4
```

Generate the lists of divisors, from `1` to `10000`. (the lists of divisors are sorted automatically)

```
Count[ ..., a_/; ... ]
```

Count the occurrences of elements `a`, such that...

```
#+a[[i=⌈Tr[1^a]/2⌉]]>a[[-i]]]
```

`(input) + (left one of the middle element(s)) > (right one of the middle element(s))`  If there is only one middle element, left = right.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
4°ƒNÑÂα{нI‹O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//zTCsMaSTsORw4LOsXvQvUnigLlP//83Nzc)

**Explanation**

```
4°ƒ            # for N in [0 ... 10**4] do:
   NÑ          # push divisors of N 
     Â         # bifurcate
      α        # element-wise absolute difference
       {       # sort
        н      # pop the head (smallest difference)
         I‹    # is it smaller than the input?
           O   # sum the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
1e4:"@Z\2Y"dJ2/)G<vs
```

The code times out in TIO. Here's an example run with the offline compiler:

```
>> matl 1e4:"@Z\2Y"dJ2/)G<vs
> 13
1201
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 91 bytes

```r
function(n)sum(sapply(1:1e4,function(x,d=(1:x)[x%%1:x<1])diff(d[median(seq(d))+.5*0:1]))<n)
```

Takes a different (worse) approach to computing the DMDP than [MickyT's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141007/67312) by using array indexing and `diff` to compute it. Alas.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PclBCoMwEEbhvfcQ5q@hJFA3Yk4iXUgnA4E6VaOQnj5m5erB@/YivsipnyP@lBTpXCjN6/r9kxtceJnbsmFfX8aU27Z2dG9wFCGelsBxVkphIwa6Z/@wQ1WMiiLk0Aj11lqUCw)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 78 bytes

```
(s=#;Tr[1^Select[Table[#2-#&@@Quantile[Divisors@i,{.5,.51}],{i,10^4}],#<s&]])&
```

Comment: `Cases` is `4` bytes shorter: `Tr[1^Cases[Table[#2-#&@@Quantile[Divisors@i,{.5,.51}],{i,10^4}],s_/;s<#]]&`. See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141021/61980).

Comment: @ngenisis `Count` is even shorter: `Count[Table[#2-#&@@Quantile[Divisors@i,{.5,.51}],{i,10^‌​4}],s_/;s<#]&`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>119</s> 115 bytes

```
(n=#;Tr[1^Select[Last@#-First@#&/@(Take[Divisors@#,Round[{-.1,.1}+(1+Length@Divisors@#)/2]]&/@Range@10000),#<n&]])&
```

I *finally* got this thing working and I've been trying for the past half an hour. ._.

### Example run

[image: no description for you!]

Comment: `Cases` is `4` bytes shorter: `Tr[1^Cases[Last@#-First@#&/@(Take[Divisors@#,Round[{-.1,.1}+(1+Length@Divisors@#)/2]]&/@Range@10000),n_/;n<#]]&`. See [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141021/61980).

Comment: @ngenisis actually `Count` is even shorter than `Cases`. `Count[Last@#-First@#&/@(Take[Divisors@#,Round[{-.1,.1}+‌​(1+Length@Divisors@#‌​)/2]]&/@Range@10000)‌​,n_/;n<#]&`

Comment: Also, `10^4` or `1*^4` is shorter than `10000`, and `/@Range@` is equaivalent to `~Array~`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
#ȯV<⁰Sz≠↔§f`¦ḣḣ□100
```

No TIO link, since it times out.
[This version](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/nE@jCbR40bgqsedS541Dbl0PK0hEPLHu5YDESGBgb///83BAA) uses 100 in place of 10000 and finishes in a couple of seconds.

### Explanation

Husk has no divisors built-in or support for scientific notation yet.

```
#ȯV<⁰Sz≠↔§f`¦ḣḣ□100  Input is n (accessed with ⁰).
               □100  Square of 100: 10000
              ḣ      Inclusive range from 1.
#                    Count number of elements for which
 ȯ                   this composition of 3 functions gives truthy result:
                       Argument k, say k = 12.
         §f`¦ḣ         Divisors of k:
             ḣ           Range: [1,2,3,..,12]
         §f              Filter by
           `¦            divides k: [1,2,3,4,6,12]
     Sz≠↔              Absolute differences of divisor pairs:
        ↔                Reverse: [12,6,4,3,2,1]
     Sz                  Zip with divisor list
       ≠                 using absolute difference: [11,4,1,1,4,11]
  V<⁰                  Is any of these less than n?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>25</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
L²õÈâ ®aX/ZÃd<UÃè
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TLL1yOIgrmFYL1rDZDxVw+g=&input=MTM=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
L²õ
```

Generate an array of integers (`õ`) from 1 to 100 (`L`) squared.

```
Èâ          Ã
```

Pass each through a function (where `X` is the current element) that generates an array of the divisors (`â`) of `X`.

```
®    Ã
```

Map over that array of divisors, where `Z` is the current element.

```
aX/Z
```

Get the absolute difference (`a`) of `Z` and `X` divided by `Z`.

```
d<U
```

Are any of the elements (`d`) in the resulting array less than `U`?

```
è
```

Count the truthy elements and implicitly output the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 62 bytes

```rb
->n{(1..1e4).count{|x|(1..x).any?{|i|1>x%i&&x/i<=i&&i-x/i<n}}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNQT88w1URTLzm/NK@kuqaiBiRSoamXmFdpX12TWWNoV6GaqaZWoZ9pYwukM3VBrLza2tr/BaUlxQpp0aYGBgax/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 46 bytes

Note that TI-BASIC is a tokenized language. Also, the E in line 2 is a small capital E, found by pressing 2ND+, .

```
Input A
DelVar DFor(B,1,E4
For(C,1,√(B
If not(fPart(B/C
B/C-C<A
End
D+Ans→D
End
```

Result will be in D, and Ans immediately after program execution. If it is to be displayed, adding two more bytes (newline and `Ans`) would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 134 bytes

```python
lambda i:len(filter(lambda n:n<i,[reduce(lambda x,y:y-x,[[x,n/x]for x in range(1,int(n**.5+1))if n%x<1][-1])for n in range(1,10001)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BDsIgEEX3nmI2JqCjgkabEj0JsqgKSlKnDcWEnr6Wqombv3jz/s@0fXw0tB3c6TzU1fNyq8Cr2hJzvo42sC8jRUePOtjb62p/MGGv@lVCrRPSJhnXBEjgCUJFd8skeoqMFov1fik59w5ono7S6JU0PLv070ohhOSG8yHaLnZwAi0R9ghyh7A7lAhFUSBsR23EU5ZT5qL4HISZzfKwz8PTjII2jF@AY54Pbw)

Eugh... need to do *much* better.

Comment: [125 bytes (-9 bytes)](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoIwEEX3fMVsTFoctIUggcCX1C5QQJvIQHgk5euR4mNzF3PPnNx@mZ4dhWtTXNdX2d6qEkw2zi2j3EDTDUBgSA11Nd9r9gUsLtkSWFTKIp2tdpjdMBhKetRMoqGJke@f4qPk3DRAB5tLrQKp@U/5Z6UQQnLN16kepxEKUBIhRpARQnRJEZIkQQg3ajvvme7p/sSnENrznNc4767JoB@2EdAww9c3) using your current approach, but replacing `len(filter(lambda n:n<i,...))` with `sum(n<i for n in ....)`

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwEEX3nGI2Ji0O2mKQQOAk2AVK0SZSCJSknL626MLNX/x5/2WmzbxGnbq@vrl3O9y7FlS5rAOZZbc@JPl1FrdySyw2jUV9tqIfZ7CgNMytfkrCUWlDdByfsiOnVPWgD7biokm4oJWCgOt/nDPGPOiMXMwCNTQcIUPgF4TLtUDI8xwh9ZCv9yz2DDP2PTARRUGrgnbXlDDN/g3oiaLuAw) based on Mr.Xcoder''s comment.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwEEX3nGI2JgUHbTFIIOJFahcooE2kkFKScvraogs3f/Hn/ZeZVvMaVeb6@ubezXBvG5DVvAxEXnXXLo@O/FqLa7WmFjm3qI5W9KMGC1KBbtSzIwylMkQlySHfsziWPaidvTDBUybiwKp/llFKPeVMN5sZauAMIUdgJ4TTuUQoigIh85Cvtyy3DDP6PVARRUErg3bTVDBp/wP0RMbuAw) based on ovs' comment.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

A bit on the slow side, uses 5 seconds per test case

```python
lambda x:sum(x>min(abs(y/t-t)for t in range(1,y+1)if y%t<1)for y in range(1,10001))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1dC4IwFIav81ecm2CjE22KiZL9kYqY5WqQU9wJ3K9fTejj5r143q/B0723adD1MTxU11wVTJV7dmzad8Yy1TjmN7QmrvsRCIyFUdlbyyT6leRGg1/STs6u/3elEEJyHqh1dL4o1zqo4SAxR5lhti2xKApM3yHMo5RRYkfMUJyS@e9Tjsu/pSpZDKOxBJp9IQ8v)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 94+1 bytes

```php
for(;$n++<1e4;$c+=$d<$argn)if(($i=$n**.5)>~~$i){while($n%++$i);for($d=1;$n%--$i;)$d++;}echo$c;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d29d5bceac53b3881f2eed6e7006def821897f88).

Answer (score 0):

## VB.NET (.NET 4.5) <s>116</s> 115 bytes

```
Function A(n)
For i=1To 10^4
Dim s As Byte=Math.Sqrt(i)
While i Mod s>0
s-=1
End While
A-=i/s-s<n
Next
End Function
```

---

Explanation:

A function that takes `n` as a parameter, and returns the result.

Starts at the square root, and looks for the nearest integer that evenly divides (will be the smaller of the `MaxMin Divisor Pair`). Then gets the larger of the pair (`i/s`), finds the difference, and compares against the input.

---

Golfing strategies used:

- `Dim` is expensive, so the fewer variables I declare the better.
- I start searching at the square root, but only want to look at integers. By declaring `s` as an integral type, it casts to the floor for me.
- VB uses `^` as exponent. So while `10000` is 5 characters, `10^4` is only 4.
- VB creates an automatic variable with the same name and type as the function definition (in my case A). At the end of the function, if there is no `return`, the value of the function variable will be returned instead. So I save characters by not declaring a separate variable and not using a return statement.
- VB has very forgiving typing/casting. `i` is assumed `Integer` because I assigned a integer literal. `A` is assumed `Object` but as soon as I add an integer, it behaves like an `Integer`.
- Rather than `if` checking the that the difference is satisfactory, add it directly to the result by casting the boolean to an integer. However, VB uses `-1` for `True`, so subtract to get the correct sign.
- Technically, we want `Mod` to not be `0`. Taking the modulus of a negative number in VB.NET will give a negative result. But, everything is positive so I can save a byte by turning `<>` into `>`.
- The largest number to check is 10000. The square root of that is 100. So I only need a `Byte` to store that, saving bytes in the declaration by using a shorter named type.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdE9b8MgEAbgnV9xW82AC01SK1JdyW2Tqc6SSNkqEfvUnOSAArgfv97FVN1qszA8d7yn44N8rztx0p4aYTCIizV2qG3bdwg1e6ELEGgPZAK@o4MbqGMBOLz25NBDi02nnQ5kjYfPM8WufLc5wDJfQWtjgbFh2PamGSugygxnW@uASnWwoOTbMkV4qDw8fQcsax3O@f7qQkacHdN7FCNb8I@SeVEqtjEtJGCVKOnWC/9g2A6/QpK/qGHfn6DWZBh7jqPZDvOjo4CvZDCrMsUhHv6vrWZMLfikLe7XfMqKopi0Oykln5plxtYzpuSI03mjsbSwuKd0/3758AM)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 104 bytes

```cs
x=>{int o=0,i=1;for(;i<=10000;i++)for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)if(i%j<1&Math.Abs(j-i/j)<x){o++;break;}return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdFBS8MwFAfws/0UYag0dJ3NSi0lTUEETw4GHjyIh6ym89WZQJLKpPSz17Rz4EGSQ/J4@RH@SWoT10qLsTMg9@jp21jxSYP6wI1B2z4wlluo0UMn6xKkXSI3VQ0bj6zqXYkUS5bACG2UDimUjCRuUIgiPHUm0brdtmRAW9eEJoSrtiTXG27fV3c7E7Yx3LS4POJeRRHdacE/6KCF7bREig4jPUf4UvCGNhxkaKx2WV9eEdd7g/vg4l5Jow5i9azBikeQIrxckLjqm5DgYYHp/yKbReYRJD0dknpMelvMyK0elef5rNzqUWv3djObCl/ys8v8rji7wu/mTztdNfHLdfI34q8cgmH8AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
Boole@Array[AtomQ@√(4a+#^2)&,#,0,Or]~Sum~{a,1*^4}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yk/PyfVwbGoKLEy2rEkPzfQ4VHHLA2TRG3lOCNNNR1lHQMd/6LYuuDS3LrqRB1DrTiTWrX/AUWZeSXRyrp2aQ7KsWp1wcmJeXXVXIY6XKY6XIbGOlzGZpY6XObm5jpcRgYGBkBhMGkJJg0NwBRIwoCr9j8A)

Slow.