# 2 factors factorization

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, integer

Given a natural number `n` write a program or function to get a list of all the possible two factors multiplications that can be used to achieve `n`. To understand better what is pretended you can go to http://factornumber.com/?page=16777216 to see when `n` is `16777216` we get the following list:

```
   2 × 8388608  
   4 × 4194304  
   8 × 2097152  
  16 × 1048576  
  32 ×  524288  
  64 ×  262144  
 128 ×  131072  
 256 ×   65536  
 512 ×   32768  
1024 ×   16384
2048 ×    8192
4096 ×    4096
```

No need to pretty print things like here. The requirement is that each entry (pair of factors) is well distinguished from each other and inside each pair, the first factor is also well distinguished from the other. If you choose to return a list/array, the inside element can be a list/array with two elements, or some structure of your language that supports a pair of things like C++ `std::pair`.

Do not print the multiplication by 1 entry, nor repeat entries with the first factor commuted by the second, as they are pretty useless.

No winner; it will be a per language basis code golf.

Comment: Could you possibly add a smaller test case, such as `30`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing You can use [factornumber.com](http://factornumber.com/?page=30) to generate more test cases.

Comment: I've seen this "per language" competition recently. What's the point? Most Qs don't get more than 1 or 2 As per language, and you still can select just one A as correct.

Comment: @fedes. It's usually because there's no point in comparing between languages (i.e. Java vs. Jelly).

Comment: @totallyhuman yeah, I know. Most of my answers are in Factor, or even Smalltalk. No chance against the golfing languages. Maybe there could be some way of ranking languages by verbosity and boilerplatery

Comment: Related https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/141004/73398

Answer (score 6):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>81</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

- -15 Bytes thanks to Olivier Grégoire.
- -1 Byte: `++j<=i/j` -> `j++<i/j`.

```java
i->{for(int j=1;j++<i/j;)if(i%j<1)System.out.println(j+" "+i/j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsIwFEX3fsVDEBKK0SrYIeri5ODUURxibPXFNinNS0Gk316juLhezuUco3o1c21pzfUx6lp5D0eF9pUAeFKEGkwkRCCsRRWsJnRWHCztnfWhKTu4w3bE2e5VuY6hJTDbTJo03eDcSI4Vw6nZZLx4eiob4QKJtotYbZlJJzBJI8blMMokCttwqaPw5@0dXqGJLaygeLmdzqD4pwvuQmldtsSydZ7ny2zN5d@8WnyHIRnGNw)

---

Old one (for reference)

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 126 bytes

```java
i->{java.util.stream.IntStream.range(2,i).filter(d->d<=i/d&&i%d==0).forEach(e->System.out.println(""+e+"x"+i/e));return null;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9Ba4NAEIXv/opBaFgxbpoc4sHoLYEeegr0UnrYuhMdu46y7oaG4G@3Wxro7THzHnxfp64qG0bkTn8ttVHTBK@K@B4BTE45qqELDekdGXnxXDsaWJ4e4fDCDhu0a3gbSFfQQrlQVt3/J5OzqHoZeue/ZBU3KHZrSuSFjEMrdFbpQ0kbvVrRky7L5/AZ7FHVrcCsOt8mh70cvJOjJXaGRRynmMbfcUobTJLCovOWgb0xxbwUUSAf/acJ5A@Ba2CDPkiJwEDcvH@ASn4FoZVqHM1NbPd5nu@2@6QI1zmalx8)

First codegolf submit and first lambda usage. Future self, please forgive me for the code.

Comment: Nice first entry! Welcome to PPCG! Here is it golfed down to [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwFEV3vuKFxKQNoQYHGQouTg5OjsahFpBXoSX01cQYvh1r4npzbs4x6qVyN7XWNM9VD8p7OCu0nwTAkyLUYCIhAuEgumA1obPiZOnorA9jO0MP9Yr54dO5maElMHUhs8xUNW6N5Ngx3Jiq4Je3p3YULpCY5sgNlpkshTSLGJfLKpNonMJ9iMa/@OWwgTHGsAvFy@N6A8V/YdALpXU7ESv2ZVnuij2XcV6SZf0C) by removing all the superfluous: I couldn't golf your algorithm though.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n/k/k*[f]and[(k,n/k)][n%k:]+f(n,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU8n29bIKk8/Wz9bKzotNjEvJVojWwfI14yNzlPNtorVTtMAqtE21PxfUJSZV6KQpmGmyQVjGiOxTQw0/wMA)

---

**51 bytes** (thanks to Luis Mendo for a byte)

```python
lambda n:[(n/k,k)for k in range(1,n)if(k*k<=n)>n%k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlojTz9bJ1szLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdPMzNNI1sr28Y2T9MuTzU79n9BUWZeiUKahqEmF4xphmAaI7FNDDT/AwA)

---

**51 bytes**

```python
lambda n:[(n/k,k)for k in range(1,n)if n/k/k>n%k*n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlojTz9bJ1szLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdPMzNNASinn22Xp5qtlRf7v6AoM69EIU3DUJMLxjRDMI2R2CYGmv8B)

Comment: I like the use of `[f]`.

Comment: You can save 1 byte in the second version with `lambda n:[(n/k,k)for k in range(1,n)if(k*k<=n)>n%k]`

Comment: MemoryError on all approaches for 1512518520

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61405/steadybox).

```c
f(N,j){for(j=1;j++*j<N;)N%j||printf("|%d,%d",j,N/j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9Nw08nS7M6Lb9II8vW0DpLW1sry8bPWtNPNaumpqAoM68kTUOpRjVFRzVFSSdLx08/S9O69n9uYmaehmY1F2eahgIYGBtoWheUlhRrKClpWoOEDc3Mzc2NDM2QhWv/AwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ÑÂ‚ø2äн¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f8wNWFiMWX//8ORw4LigJrDuDLDpNC9wqb//zE2Nzc3MjE2)

Comment: +1 from me we have nearly the same solutions. I thought of this [8-byter](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v8wNWFiMWX//8ORw4LigJrDuOKCrHvDmcKm//8zMA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Ah yes, nice :) It's too bad that the map is required there.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```
f x=[(a,b)|a<-[2..x],b<-[2..a],a*b==x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjZaI1EnSbMm0UY32khPryJWJwnCSozVSdRKsrWtiP2fm5iZp2CrUFCUmVeioKKQpmBs8B8A)

Comment: Time out for 1512518520

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 bytes

```apl
{(⊢,⍵÷⊢)¨o/⍨0=⍵|⍨o←1↓⍳⌊⍵*.5}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqjUddi3Qe9W49vB3I0Dy0Il//Ue8KA1ugSA2QkQ9UYviobfKj3s2PerqAglp6prX//z/qXZWmYGjEpW5ra6vOBeGZmZubGxmaAQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 38 bytes

```perl6
{map {$^a,$_/$a},grep $_%%*,2.. .sqrt}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWnJ@SqmD7vzo3sUChWiUuUUclXl8lsVYnvSi1QEElXlVVS8dIT09Br7iwqKT2v15xYqVCWn6RAliboZm5ubmRodl/AA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{   # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  map
    { $^a, $_ / $a },  # map the number with the other factor

    grep
      $_ %% *,         # is the input divisible by *
      2 .. .sqrt       # from 2 to the square root of the input
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
{~×≜Ċo}ᵘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7ru8PRHnXOOdOXXPtw64/9/Y4P/UQA)

### Explanation

```
{~×≜Ċo}ᵘ
{     }ᵘ  List the unique outputs of this predicate.
 ~×       Pick a list of integers whose product is the input.
   ≜      Force concrete values for its elements.
    Ċ     Force its length to be 2.
     o    Sort it and output the result.
```

The `~×` part does not include 1s in its output, so for input **N** it gives **[N]** instead of **[1,N]**, which is later culled by `Ċ`.
I'm not entirely sure why `≜` is needed...

Comment: The `≜` is needed because otherwise there are no choice points for `ᵘ`: a length-2 list whose product is the input is the only answer if you don't actually ask for the values of the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 7 bytes

```
ḊŒċP=¥Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq6jk450B9geWnqs/b@xgQJQ4OGO@YfbghSsDU1MFHQUDrcfnfRw5wwVBZVHTWsUvIFE5H8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
â¬Å£[XZo]
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4qzFo1tYWm9d&input=MjU2IC1S) Returns an array of arrays, with some nulls at the end; `-R` flag added to show output more clearly.

Comment: So I think the ` -R` should be considered for the byte count...

Comment: @sergiol, no, in this case it's just for formatting the output for better readability.

Comment: Exactly the solution I had, except I filtered the `null`s out at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 55 bytes

```js
n=>eval('for(k=1,a=[];k*++k<n;n%k||a.push([k,n/k]));a')
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>eval('for(k=1,a=[];k*++k<n;n%k||a.push([k,n/k]));a')

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(6)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(7)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(16777216)))
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/%23%23BcFRDoMgDADQ0yy2UzFunwwvYvxoGExX0hpRv7w7vvenk7LflnVvRb@hRFfEDeGkBFXUDdj1Dblxsvysa/6IlQdfF5n1yDOM3EjHE6KlCotXyZqCSfqDCP3rjVhu)

Comment: Is it me or does this fail for `6`?

Comment: @Neil ["We can fix it."](https://youtu.be/kayFrIR-Qfw?t=1m13s) (Thanks for reporting!)

Comment: How can I supply a number to test?

Comment: You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRDoMgDADQ0yy2UzFunwwvYvxoGExX0hpRv7w7vvenk7LflnVvRb@hRFfEDeGkBFXUDdj1Dblxsvysa/6IlQdfF5n1yDOM3EjHE6KlCotXyZqCSfqDCP3rjVhu "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
½ḊpP⁼¥Ðf
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of lists (pairs) of numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//wr3huIpwUOKBvMKlw5Bm////MTQ0)** (times out on TIO for the `16777216` example since it would create a list of 68.7 billion pairs and filter down to those with the correct product!)

#### How?

```
½ḊpP⁼¥Ðf - Link: number, n     e.g. 144
½        - square root of n          12
 Ḋ       - dequeue*                 [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  p      - Cartesian product**      [[2,1],[2,2],...[2,144],[3,1],...,[3,144],...,[12,144]
      Ðf - filter keep if:
     ¥   -   last two links as a dyad (n is on the right):
   P     -     product
    ⁼    -     equals
         -                          [[2,72],[3,48],[4,36],[6,24],[8,18],[9,16],[12,12]]
```

* `Ḋ`, dequeue, implicitly makes a range of a numeric input prior to acting, and the range function implicitly floors its input, so with, say, `n=24` the result of `½` is `4.898...`; the range becomes `[1,2,3,4]`; and the dequeued result is `[2,3,4]`

** Similarly to above, `p`, Cartesian product, makes ranges for numeric input - here the right argument is `n` hence the right argument becomes `[1,2,3,...,n]` prior to the actual Cartisian product taking place.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
tüOSze↔Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v@TwHv/gqtRHbVMe7uj6//@/mQEA)

### Explanation

```
tüOSze↔Ḋ  Implicit input, say n=30.
       Ḋ  List of divisors: [1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30]
      ↔   Reverse: [30,15,10,6,5,3,2,1]
   Sze    Zip with original: [[1,30],[2,15],[3,10],[5,6],[6,5],[10,3],[15,2],[30,1]]
 üO       Deduplicate by sort: [[1,30],[2,15],[3,10],[5,6]]
t         Drop first pair: [[2,15],[3,10],[5,6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda N:{(n,N/n,n)[n>N/n:][:2]for n in range(2,N)if N%n<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoQgGAbQq/ybAQUhdJEg1RG8gNPCoZwR6jNMgiE6uzPtHrztWz4Jqob@WRe/viZP1pwMwjYQ4A7DH2Z0Ro0hZQJFUPZ4z0wJy2Mg@0Anr3rnceeecpknFphstdZKtpybLUcUOuoP)

Comment: https://tio.run/##FcnRCoMgFAbgVzk3AwVh84AQsu0RfIHqwig3YfsNk2BEz27r7oNv/pV3Atfw6OrHf4fRk7ObgHJXKMgWzz9s31ruQ8oEiqDs8ZoEKydjIHfBXe/1zPXMJeUyjSIIbTQb3Ri@SWnnHFForQc — Memory error?

Comment: @sergiol Yes, a MemoryError, since Python tries to evaluate `range(2,N)` and store it as a list, yet the allocated memory does not suffice. One could try replace `range` with `xrange` (Python 2's range generator), though this exceeds TIO's one minute of maximum runtime. On a machine with enough memory and time, this program should terminate and return the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ÆḌḊµżUṢ€Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//w4bhuIzhuIrCtcW8VeG5ouKCrFH///8zMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 42 bytes

```matlab
@(n)[y=find(~mod(n,x=2:n)&x.^2<=n)+1;n./y]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08zutI2LTMvRaMuNz9FI0@nwtbIKk9TrUIvzsjGNk9T29A6T0@/MvZ/moahmbm5uZGhmeZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes

As string (70 bytes):

```
$i++;while($i++<sqrt($a=$argv[1])){echo !($a%$i)?" {$i}x".($a/$i):'';}
```

As array dump (71 bytes):

```
$i++;while($i++<sqrt($a=$argv[1]))!($a%$i)?$b[$i]=$a/$i:'';print_r($b);
```

(im not sure if i can use return $b; instead of print_r since it no longer outputs the array, otherwise i can save 2 bytes here. )

The array gives the results like:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 8388608
    [4] => 4194304
    [8] => 2097152
    [16] => 1048576
```

Comment: "If you choose to return a list/array" To me it means you can print or return as you see fit.

Comment: On second thought, returning should be valid for a function, and printing for a program. You seem to have a snippet/program, not a function, so I'd say in this case you should be printing.

Answer (score 1):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
nRest@Union[Sort@{#,n/#}&/@Divisors@n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P@/9pIVBqcUlDqF5mfl50cH5RSUO1co6efrKtWr6Di6ZZZnF@UXFDnmx/wOKMvNKHNKiDc3Mzc2NDM1i/wMA)

`` is the `Function` operator, which introduces an unnamed function with named parameter `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org), 58

Well, there has to be some Factor in this question!

```
[ divisors dup reverse zip dup length 1 + 2 /i head rest ]
```

It's a quotation. `call` it with the number on the stack, leaves an `assoc` (an array of pairs) on the stack.

I'm never sure if all the imports count or not, as they're part of the language.
This one uses:

```
USING: math.prime.factors sequences assocs math ;
```

(If they count, I should look for a longer solution with shorter imports, which is kind of silly)

As a word:

```
: 2-factors ( x -- a ) divisors dup reverse zip dup length 1 + 2 /i head rest ;

50 2-factors .
 --> { { 2 25 } { 5 10 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2..n**0.5).map{|x|[[x,n/x]][n%x]}-[p]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNITy9PS8tAz1RTLzexoLqmoiY6ukInT78iNjY6T7UitlY3uiC29n@BQlq0oZm5ubmRoVnsfwA)

#### How it works:

For every number up to sqrt(n), generate the pair `[[x, n/x]]`, then take the `n%x`th element of this array. If `n%x==0` this is `[x, n/x]`, otherwise it's `nil`. when done, remove all `nil` from the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>49</s> <s>34</s> 38 bytes

```
n->[[d,n/d]|d<-divisors(n),d>1&d<=n/d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuOjpFJ08/JbYmxUY3JbMsszi/qFgjT1Mnxc5QLcXGFiT1v6AoM69EI03D2ERTkwvCgdFAQVNsgmbYBM2xCBqamZubGxkC1f8HAA)

Set builder notation for all pairs `[d, n/d]` where `d` runs through all divisors `d` of `n` subject to `d > 1` and `d <= n/d`.

Huge improvement by alephalpha.

Comment: [`n->[[d,n/d]|d<-divisors(n),d<=n/d]`](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifZvs/T9cuOjpFJ08/JbYmxUY3JbMsszi/qFgjT1MnxcYWJPy/oCgzr0QjTcPYRFOTC8KB0UBBU2yCZtgEzbEIGpqZm5sbGQLV/wcA "Pari/GP – Try It Online")

Comment: @alephalpha Good one. But had to change it a bit because it output also the factorization with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 53 + 2 (`-p` flag) = 55 bytes

```
$_="@{[map{$_,$n/$_.$/}grep!($n%$_),2..sqrt($n=$_)]}"
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
while (defined $_ = <>) {
    $n = $_;
    $_ = qq(@{[
        map{ ($_, ($n / $_) . "\n") } grep { !($n % $_) } (2 .. sqrt($n))
    ]});
    print($_);
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbJoTo6N7GgWiVeRyVPXyVeT0W/Nr0otUBRQyVPVSVeU8dIT6@4sKgEyLUFcmNrlf7/NzQzNzc3MjTj@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
K~/Z's⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K%7E%2FZ%27s%E2%81%BC&inputs=4096&header=&footer=)

(not anymore) messy.

Comment: [7 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=K~%2FZ's%E2%81%BC&inputs=4096&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller Nice use of `~` :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
tumoOSe`/⁰Ḋ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v6Q0N98/ODVB/1Hjhoc7uoDk////jQ0A)

#### Explanation

```
tum(OSe`/⁰)Ḋ⁰  -- input ⁰, eg. 30
           Ḋ⁰  -- divisors [1..⁰]: [1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30]
  m(      )    -- map the following function (example on 10):
     Se        --   create list with 10 and ..
       `/⁰     --   .. flipped division by ⁰ (30/10): [10,3]
    O          --   sort: [3,10]
               -- [[1,30],[2,15],[3,10],[5,6],[5,6],[3,10],[2,15],[1,30]]
 u             -- remove duplicates: [[1,30],[2,15],[3,10],[5,6]]
t              -- tail: [[2,15],[3,10],[5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 32 bytes

```
m,[.1]n÷m←(0=m|n)/m←1↓⍳⌊(n←⎕)*.5
```

Explanation:

```
(n←⎕) Prompts for screen input

m←(0=m|n)/m←1↓⍳⌊(n←⎕)*.5 Calculates the factors dropping the first

m,[.1]n÷ Identifies the pairs and concatenates into a list.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
L,F@pB]dBRBcE#S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx82hwCk2xSnIKdlVOTgs2f3////GBgA)

### How it works

```
L,   - Create a lambda function
     - Example argument:     30
  F  - Factors;     STACK = [1 2 3 5 6 10 15]
  @  - Reverse;     STACK = [15 10 6 5 3 2 1]
  p  - Pop;         STACK = [15 10 6 5 3 2]
  B] - Wrap;        STACK = [[15 10 6 5 3 2]]
  d  - Duplicate;   STACK = [[15 10 6 5 3 2] [15 10 6 5 3 2]]
  BR - Reverse;     STACK = [[15 10 6 5 3 2] [2 3 5 6 10 15]]
  Bc - Zip;         STACK = [[15 2] [10 3] [6 5] [5 6] [3 10] [2 15]]
  E# - Sort each;   STACK = [[2 15] [3 10] [5 6] [5 6] [3 10] [2 15]]
  S  - Deduplicate; STACK = [[[2 15] [3 10] [5 6]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, 56 bytes

```
&1vg00,+55./.:   <
+1< v`\g00/g00:p00
_ ^@_::00g%!00g\#v
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X82wLN3AQEfb1FRPX89KQUHBhkvb0EahLCEGKKwPxFYFBgZc8QpxDvFWVgYG6aqKQCJGuez/f0MjAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 53 bytes

```
Array[s[[{#,-#}]]&,⌈Length[s=Divisors@#]/2⌉-1,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b737GoKLEyujg6ulpZR1e5NjZWTedRT4dPal56SUZ0sa1LZllmcX5RsYNyrL7Ro55OXUMdo1i1/wFFmXklDmnRhmbm5uZGhmax/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
~x=[(y,div(x,y))for y=2:x if x%y<1>y^2-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/rsI2WqNSJyWzTKNCp1JTMy2/SKHS1siqQiEzTaFCtdLG0K4yzki3IvY/UCY1MTlDo6AoM68kJ0@nztDM3NzcyNBM8z8A)

Redefines the inbuild unary operator `~` and uses an array comprehension to build the output.

- `div(x,y)` is neccessary for integer division. `x/y` saves 5 bytes but the output is `~4=(2,2.0)`.
- Julia allows chaining the comparisons, saving one byte.
- Looping all the way to x avoids `Int(floor(√x))`.

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 99 chars

```
r←f w;i;h
r←⍬⋄i←1⋄→0×⍳0≠⍴⍴w⋄→0×⍳''≡0↑w⋄→0×⍳w≠⌊w⋄→0×⍳w≠+w
A:i+←1⋄→A×⍳∼0=i∣w⋄→0×⍳i>h←w÷i⋄r←r,⊂i h⋄→A
```

9+46+41+3=99 Test: (where not print nothing, it return something it return ⍬ the list null one has to consider as "no solution")

```
  f 101    

  f 1 2 3

  f '1'

  f '123'

  f 33 1.23

  f 1.23

  ⎕←⊃f 16777216      
   2 8388608
   4 4194304
   8 2097152
  16 1048576
  32  524288
  64  262144
 128  131072
 256   65536
 512   32768
1024   16384
2048    8192
4096    4096
  f 123
3 41
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```
←ĐðĐ0↔/⅟ƖŽĐŁ₂20`ŕ3ȘĐ05Ș↔ŕ↔Đ4Ș⇹3Ș⦋ƥ⇹⁺Ɩ3ȘĐ05Ș↔ŕ↔Đ4Ș⇹3Ș⦋ƤĐ3Ș⁺ƖĐ3Ș<łĉ
```

I'm pretty sure this can be golfed.

Basically, the algorithm generates a list of all of the divisors of the input (let's call it *n*), makes the same list, but flipped, interleaves the two (e.g., if *n*=24, then, at this point, it has [1,24,2,12,3,8,4,6,6,4,8,3,12,2,24,1]), and prints out the elements from index 2 until half the array length, printing each number on a new line, and with an extra new line in between every pair.

Most of the work is done in actually managing the stack.

Saved 2 bytes by using increment function.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 50 bytes

```
sub{map[$_,$_[0]/$_],grep!($_[0]%$_),2..sqrt$_[0]}
```

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub {
    return map  { [$_, $_[0] / $_] }
           grep { !($_[0] % $_) }
           (2 .. sqrt($_[0]));
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcquCSWJJoZeVSmluQWmTNlVupoJKmYKvwv7g0qTo3sSBaJV5HJT7aIFZfJT5WJ70otUBRA8xXVYnX1DHS0ysuLCoBC9T@t@YqKMrMK9GAmKURrZKma6dhaGZubm5kaKYZq6lp/R8A).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a 2D array.

```
â ¤ò
£ÎîX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4iCk8gqjzu5Y&input=MTY3NzcyMTYKLVI)