# Find the absolute minimum difference between 2 divided numbers from n

Tags: code-golf, math

### Input:

An integer `n`

### Output:

A string `A * B`

### Example

`12`

Possible 2 divisible numbers: `12 * 1`, `6 * 2`, `4 * 3`

```
12-1 = 11

6-2 = 4

4-3 = 1
```

4 and 3 has the minimal absolute difference of 1

Therefore, Output:

`4 * 3`

*Order of the numbers does **not** matter*

*This challenge idea was taken from a puzzle in Clash of Code in https://www.codingame.com*

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: your sandbox post?

Comment: I got this idea from a puzzle in Clash of Code in codingame.com

Comment: Can we just output a pair of integers?

Comment: You have to output the pair of integers with the asterisk in the middle

Comment: I would personally recommend against that because it does not really add to the challenge in terms of making it interesting, and detracts from the core of the challenge. Of course it's up to you but that is just my personal advice based on typical I/O formats and conventions.

Comment: Related: [Find the Squarish Root](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167149/20260)

Comment: I see thanks hyper-neutrino usually i am a average coder so im happy to take advice from higher level programmers!

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be a positive integer, or can it be negative?

Comment: Is the space around star sign required?

Comment: Except for the requirement that the numbers have to be separated by an asterisk, this appears to be a duplicate of:  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/minimum-perimeter-of-an-area/18355#18355

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
KḂZµƒε;h×YṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJL4biCWsK1xpLOtTtow5dZ4bmEIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==)

-2 thanks to lyxal

```
K           # Factors
 ḂZ         # Zipped with reverse
   µ  ;h    # Minimum by
    ƒε      # Reduced by abs. diff.
        ×Y  # Interleave with '*'
          Ṅ # Join by spaces
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJL4biCWsK1xpLOtTtow5dZ4bmEIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==) for 11

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 74 bytes

```python
def f(x):q=[i for i in range(1,1+x)if x%i<1];q=q[len(q)/2];print q,"*",x/q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQ@74iCINkK5T2pq5fIh4GNhqQaEoP3dd3792/elwae98yA2OjydIiwFcBAVEoX90zBhfejYShPeUT1tmSLWdWNPJxne8iWsHc8Bpc89YZR3owhkj9Dw)

Comment: is it possible to remove the function? sry i have not tried python 2 yet only python3x

Comment: @DialFrost [this](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAe69YgkBLED3nS8RDB62FWF0xsNdbc57ytiuTHaM7pPI0ISd2HiHlCghIUA86ozDKbF1igr7gbsJ/2N@RBEttw1QqUgNW8zqrrnkMYz8) is 1 byte longer

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 55 bytes

```
f=lambda n,m=1:n%m|(m*m<n)and f(n,m+1)or`n/m`+" * "+`m`
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN83TbHMSc5NSEhXydHJtDa3yVHNrNHK1cm3yNBPzUhTSNIDC2oaa-UUJefq5CdpKCloKStoJuQlQ7eoFRZl5JRppGoZGmppccI4ZMsfQWFMTohxmKwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 13 bytes

```
ÆDżU$ạ/ÞḢj”*K
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLDhkTFvFUk4bqhL8Oe4biiauKAnSpLIiwiIiwiIixbIjEyIl1d)

-1 byte thanks to a golf from lyxal ported by emanresu A
-1 byte thanks to emanresu A

```
ÆDżU$ạ/ÞḢj”*K  Main Link
ÆD             Divisor List
  żU$          Interleaved with its reverse
       Þ       Sorted by
     ạ/        Absolute Difference
        Ḣ      Get the first one
         j”*   Join on "*"
            K  Join on spaces
```

Comment: Could you split the code out and explain like how emanresu A did? (Jelly is hard to read XD)

Comment: @emanresuA oh clever

Comment: [-1 more 'cos sort's shorter](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//w4ZExbxVJOG6oS/DnuG4omrigJ0qS////zEy)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 104 bytes

```
lambda n:'%d * %d'%min([(x,n/x)for x in[i for i in range(1,n)if(n/i)%1==0]],key=lambda x:abs(x[0]-x[1]))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3LDoIwEIXhvU8xm4YZg4FqvJH0SWoXJVCdKANBFuXpERNNuvv@zTnDPD16OSzB3JaX7@rGg1SZamALqslUx4IWYy5FpNCPEIHFMnzJK2H0cm9R50IcUAompY0pncuf7Wx@e7Hy9RujLd0uWu2IlmFkmTDgkWjz9ynxOfEl8TWxLtPQaezXiw8)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 96 bytes

```
f=lambda x:(lambda y:str(z:=y[len(y)//2])+" * "+str(x//z))([i for i in range(1,x) if x/i==x//i])
```

Comment: what python is this? please specify

Comment: @DialFrost It's Python 3 as you can tell by `//` and `:=`

Comment: if im right there is no such character as := in python3 and please try to use tio.run to show that it works thanks

Comment: @DialFrost there is in python 3.8+. here's a TIO link: https://tio.run/##LcrBCoMwDIDhVwmekjkIusso9EnEQ4d2C7hYsh5aX76bsNsP359qfu16uydrLfotvB9LgOLwX9V9suHhfJ22VbES8zhT38EFuv6kwnwQ4SQQdwMBUbCgzxWHayGQCIXF@98lM7VkohkjDiNR@wI

Comment: you can save 2 bytes by dropping the `f=` at the top (put ``f=\`` into the header for testing) since we allow anonymous function submissions

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=n**.5|(-n)**.5)=>n%i?f(n,i+1):i+' * '+(n/i|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlBCoMwEAC/speSXdOkLVIPtmkf4QuCGtkiG4mhJ/@eamFgBubjv37tEy/ZSBzGEtwOypmdVJW9b2iEjiD3khO/w7H0jVrWCipQGuXC25VKiAmQwYGpmwcwPB38Q2uCPsoa59HOcUK2OXY5sUxIdvFDl33KWBNoUC2oXQGZqPwA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=n**.5|0)=>n%i?f(n,i+1):i+' * '+n/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYhBCsIwEAC/shfJbqPRUvRQjT6iLwhtU1bKbkmDJ/8eIwzMMO/wCfuYeMsn0Wku0VdQjuyladz1eyH/lAO/4v/Zlnq2BhowVs5coiZABg/tHRgeHrpbDWsJRpVd19mtuiC7rENOLAuS28I05JAydgQWTA@mKiITlR8)

For positive number only.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 73 bytes

```
[ divisors dup reverse zip [ first2 - abs ] infimum-by "%d * %d"vprintf ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFEV3v@KGhMUEEhn1A4yLi3EiDKV91RdpwfcKif58RaY7nHNyvbFplHy/Xa7nI4JJz3oSDqS134jiRRJpgNJ7pmhJYVRHq5sLP8q6ieMDp92hyS0cL6z/zs0ThBYSJXx5QgvPoqlBBdMrOnD0HOZQ9R8UpcMepSuW9Twmjy5bMwz5Bw)

```
                            ! 12
divisors                    ! { 1 2 3 4 6 12 }
dup                         ! { 1 2 3 4 6 12 } { 1 2 3 4 6 12 }
reverse                     ! { 1 2 3 4 6 12 } { 12 6 4 3 2 1 }
zip                         ! { { 1 12 } { 2 6 } { 3 4 } { 4 3 } { 6 2 } { 12 1 } }
[ first2 - abs ] infimum-by ! { 3 4 }
"%d * %d"vprintf            !
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 38 bytes

```
n->vecmin([abs(d-n/d)|d<-divisors(n)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/Xriw1OTczTyM6MalYI0U3Tz9FsybFRjclsyyzOL@oWCNPM1bzf0FRZl6JRpqGoZGm5n8A)